# C++ Date Parsing Implementation

Tags: c++, regex, string, validation, boost

I'm currently working to parse dates into a program.

The format can be in the following form:

```
DDMMYYYY
DDMMYY
DDMM

DD/MM/YYYY
DD/MM/YY
DD/MM
```

Do that that along with the dates, there would be other content included such as the follows:

```
19/12/12 0800 1000
```

That breaks my current implementation of using boost::date_time and tokenizer.

For the situation, what would the best suggestion? Would I be able to have a better implementation that would allow the following:

```
19 Sep 12  // DD MMM YY
```

What I had in mind was to return them as strings in the form DDMMYYYY form for use in other parts of the program. Is this the best way or are there better suggestion/alternatives?

*EDIT:

Decided that taking DDMMYYYY, DDMMYY & DDMM isn't that feasible. Shall only go with dates with backslashes.

The output remains the same though, strings in the format : DDMMYYYY

Comment: Do you know which part of the string will be the date? Then you can just extract that part and use your parser on that instead.

Comment: Nope it's highly flexible. What I had in mind was using regular expressions

Comment: Your sample data looks ambiguous.  Date could be four digits, yet in the sample there are other four-digit numbers that are not dates.  Could a case like `19/12/12   1000 0801` occur?  In that case you have two potential dates.  How would you decide which one to use?  Or would you count both as dates?

Comment: If it can really be all of this, be anywhere in the text and there can be other four, six, or eight digit numbers in it, then you are pretty much lost, as it cannot be done (without extra information).

Comment: In that situation, I'm assuming that the token with backslashes are the dates and 4 digits token are the time.

Comment: What I have in mind is the do it step by step by first extracting the time (4 digits token). Would solve the problem of matching date as time.

Comment: I would still use `boost::date_time`. First use a regex to divide the data into tokens, then pass them to boost (starting with ones that contain a `/`) and use error handling to reject the ones that aren't valid dates.  This would be more robust than trying to figure out a valid date yourself.

Comment: Create a array of facets and loop thru the tokens ?

Answer (score 2):

Using boost.regex, you can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    regex re("(\\d{2})\\/(\\d{2})(?:\\/?(\\d{2,4}))?");

    cmatch m;

    regex_search("1234 10/10/2012 4567", m, re);
    cout << m.str(1) + m.str(2) + m.str(3) << endl;
    regex_search("1234 10/10/12 4567", m, re);
    cout << m.str(1) + m.str(2) + m.str(3) << endl;
    regex_search("1234 10/10 4567", m, re);
    cout << m.str(1) + m.str(2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile like this:

```
g++ --std=c++11 -o test.a test.cpp -I[boost_path] [boost_path]/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some regexp library or builtin  **sscanf** function. It is more primitive than reg exp but can be used in your case

```
/* sscanf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   char sentence []="data 1";
   char str [16];
   int i;

   sscanf(sentence,"%s %d",str,&i);
   printf("%s -> %d\n",str,i);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work so well, as there is quite a variety of possible input.  You would end up having to scan the string many times for different possibilities, and even then you would have to verify valid months,days, etc.  If he is already using `boost`, he presumably has access to a regex library.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.

```
regex regExDate("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}");
string date = "abc:\\2016-09-12";
smatch match;

if (regex_search(date, match, regExDate))
{
 string strDate = match.str();
}
```